# Subtract value from same column based on projection

Tags: sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

I have a schema with credit movements, like the following:

```
id | orderno | due   | bookingdate | movementtype
=================================================
1  | o11     | 30.50 | 10.01.2017  | CREDIT
2  | o22     | 50.99 | 11.01.2017  | DEBIT
3  | o11     | 20.40 | 12.01.2017  | DEBIT
4  | o22     | 77.88 | 13.01.2017  | CREDIT
5  | o11     | 05.20 | 14.01.2017  | DEBIT
```

I want to retrieve the total of CREDIT minus DEBIT for a given order no and year.

So for the dummy data above, passing `orderno=o11` and `booking=2017`, I would expect `4.9`.

I came up with a query having two sub queries:

```
SELECT
  (credit - debit) AS total
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      COALESCE(SUM(due), 0.0) AS credit
    FROM
      accountactivity
    WHERE
      orderno = :ordernoParam
      AND YEAR(bookingdate) = :bookingParam
      AND movementtype = 'CREDIT'
  ),
  (
    SELECT
      COALESCE(SUM(due), 0.0) AS debit
    FROM
      accountactivity
    WHERE
      orderno = :ordernoParam
      AND YEAR(bookingdate) = :bookingParam
      AND movementtype = 'DEBIT'
  )
```

**Question:** Is it possible to optimize the query for my task? I would like to avoid sub queries for performance reasons. It should work for DB2 and Oracle 11g, either via native query or, preferably, via HibernateQL.

Comment: "I would like to avoid sub queries for performance reasons." What makes you think a subquery is detrimental to performance?

Comment: @HoneyBadger The SQL Query Optimizer notes: _"Prefer Direct Join Over Joined Subquery: The MySQL team advises against using subqueries as they are not optimized well by the optimizer. Therefore, we recommend to replace subqueries with JOIN clauses."_

Comment: So what database system do you use? Is it mySQL, DB2, Oracle or Hibernate??

Comment: @HoneyBadger If possible, I'd use a named query in HQL. If not, I need a native query which should work with both DB2 and Oracle. (I mentioned the quote from the MySQL team because I think their point applies generally.)

Comment: You cannot apply a quote about a specific database engine to all database engines. See for example [here](https://www.scarydba.com/2016/10/24/sub-query-not-hurt-performance/). A subquery is definitely not a performance killer. I've had queries with straight joins taking ages, which were optimized to mere seconds using subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `CASE`

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN movementtype = 'CREDIT' THEN due END), 0.0) -
  COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN movementtype = 'DEBIT' THEN due END), 0.0) AS total
FROM
  accountactivity
WHERE
  orderno = :ordernoParam
  AND YEAR(bookingdate) = :bookingParam
```

If you have a covering index `accountactivity(orderno)` including `bookingdate`, `movementtype`, and `due` attributes then it should be performed by one range scan.

Another issue that can be optimized is the `YEAR(bookingdate) = :bookingParam` condition. It can not be used by the query processor to search by a seek operation in an index. If you rewrite it to something like `bookingdate >= CAST('1.1.' + :bookingParam AS DATE) and bookingdate <= CAST('31.12.' + :bookingParam AS DATE)` (this can be DBMS specific) then you can have an index `accountactivity(orderno, bookingdate)` including `movementtype`, and `due` attributes and the range scan will read only relevant rows.